# Como Deserializar Json array a un objeto en c#

Tags: c#, json, array, objeto, deserialize

Hola buen dia he estado intentando se serializar este tipo de respuesta  de un string json a un objeto en c#

```
[[
"Response",
[
  {
    "root": "User quota",
    "type": "STORAGE",
    "value": "0",
    "limit": "104857600",
    "percent": "0"
  },
  {
    "root": "User quota",
    "type": "MESSAGE",
    "value": "0",
    "limit": "-",
    "percent": "0"
  }
],
"tag1"]]
```

puede que ya alla algo al respecto pero  he intentado varias cosas y simplemente no termino de comprender como hacerlo,tengo este tipo de objeto en mi codigo que me hace falta para poderlo deserializar?

```
public class Response {
    [JsonProperty("root")]
    public string Root { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("limit")]
    public string Limit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("percent")]
    public string Percent { get; set; }
}
```

estoy utilizando `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);`

Comment: parece ser una matriz, y esa matriz tiene otro array adentro. Pega ese json con visual studio, en pegado especial te da la opcion.

Comment: muchas gracis pero me da algo mu corto 

`public class Rootobject
 {
    public object[][] Property1 { get; set; }
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion fue Quitar el primer corchete  Corchetes y serializarlo, espero que a alguien le sirva esto, encuentren otra solucion

```
 PrimerSubString = RespuestaJson.Substring(result.IndexOf("[", 3));
 Resultado= PrimerSubString .Substring(0, PrimerSubString .IndexOf("]") + 1);
 var ListObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>(Resultado);
```